# discord.py main command as aliasses for command+parameter

Tags: discord.py

I have a main command like this:
`!command <parameter> <parameter>`

I want an alias function that triggers this command with a the command itself as first parameter, such as:

`!aliascommand test` would trigger `!command aliascommand test`.

How can I achieve this? I can't find any similar issues or anything useful in the docs, besides command Groups, which seem to be the other way around from what I'm trying to achieve.

Edit:
I have a list of 25 'aliascommands' I want to do this for - and rather not create 25 functions for these aliases that just call the main function. So looking for a dynamic way to do this, based of an array of strings

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in `on_message` like so:

```
cmds=message.content[1:].split()
if all(cmd in aliascommands for cmd in cmds):
    msg=message
    msg.content='!command '+msg.content[1:]
    await bot.invoke(await bot.get_context(msg))
```

This assumes `message` to be the `discord.Message` passed to `on_message`, `aliascommands` to be the list of aliases, and `bot` to be your instance of `discord.ext.commands.Bot`. This code makes a lot of assumptions, you can replace:

```
1 with the length of your bot's prefix
message with the name of the parameter passed to on_message
aliascommands with the name of the list containing the command aliases
!command with your bot's prefix + the name of the main command
bot with your bot instance
```